# How to download julia 1.3.1 using wget on CentOS7?

Tags: julia, centos7, wget

I am trying to download julia 1.3.1 using the following command:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -P="/tmp/julia" "https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
```

log:

```
[ava@srvr0 ~]$ wget --no-check-certificate -P="/tmp/julia" "https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
--2020-02-09 01:32:40--  https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
Resolving julialang-s3.julialang.org (julialang-s3.julialang.org)... 2a04:4e42:2::561, 151.101.10.49
Connecting to julialang-s3.julialang.org (julialang-s3.julialang.org)|2a04:4e42:2::561|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

stops there, no downloading.

Please help me in downloading `julia 1.3.1` using wget on CentOS7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without any from your home:

```
wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

If you have `curl` installed, you could alternatively try

```
curl https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

(MacOS users always use `curl`).

With Ubuntu Linux it the wget works ... Otherwise try to reinstall wget ...

I did it like this. And then added to my `PATH` variable (add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/julia-1.3.1/bin
```

(and execute it in your current shell) so that if you type `julia` into your shell, it finds it.

Otherwise, you can also directly start it by

```
~/julia-1.3.1/bin/julia
```

from shell.

It has not necessarily to be installed in `/tmp/` folder -